# How can I access items in a top level module from another top level module without changing main.rs?

Tags: rust

I have following file structure:

```
main.rs
-- module_a
  -- mod.rs
output.rs
```

In **output.rs**, I have a function called `log_info()` and I'd like to call it from `module_a/mod.rs`.

I can place `mod output;` in **main.rs** and after that I can reference it from **module_a/mod.rs**, but I don't like having to place all my dependencies in **main.rs** in order to use them in my application.

Is there any way I can reference the **output** module in **module_a/mod.rs** without messing with **main.rs**?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can reference the output module in module_a/mod.rs without messing with main.rs?

No. Each module (including the crate entry point of **main.rs** or **lib.rs**) has to explicitly define what modules are its children.

---

You could move the `output` module to be a child of `module_a`, however.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answer, but how can I manage this problem? When I have many shared function/modules across project. For example I put every enum to separated file, which is the problem I have. Maybe this is not the best practice how to do that.

Comment: @Legom *I put every enum to separated file* — I don't do that, so it hasn't been a problem. Most of my crates have had a small number of files; I doubt any have had more than 10, and I have one project where a single file is 200K. If you really find yourself unable to embrace such structure, you could use [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) as a terrible hack.

Comment: Yes, I have read about include but as you said, it doesn't feel right.